# Showing that $\frac{2}{3\pi}\leq\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx \leq \frac{1}{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help showing that,

$$\frac{2}{3\pi}\leq\int_{2\pi}^{3\pi}\frac{\sin x}{x} \, dx \leq \frac{1}{\pi}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the fact that $\dfrac1x$ is a decreasing function, to conclude what you want, i.e., for $0<a<b$ we have
$$\dfrac1b\int_a^b \sin(x) dx < \int_a^b \dfrac{\sin(x)}x dx < \dfrac1a\int_a^b \sin(x) dx$$
Also, note that
$$\int_{n \pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \sin(x)dx = (-1)^n \cdot 2$$

Comment: (+1) In fact you used the Bonnet's second mean value theorem? Right?